# Inner-Transparent Selection Window in Java using GlassPane

Tags: java, swing, glasspane

I am trying to achieve the following

http://www.qksnap.com/i/3hunq/4ld0v/screenshot.png

I am currently able to draw rectangles successfully on a semi-transparent glasspane background using the following code:

```
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
          Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
          g.setColor(Color.black); // black background
          g.fillRect(0, 0, frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());
          g2.setColor(Color.GREEN.darker());
          if (getRect() != null && isDrawing()) {
            g2.draw(getRect()); // draw our rectangle (simple Rectangle class)
          }
         g2.dispose();
}
```

Which works great, however, I would love to have the area within the rectangle be completely transparent while the outside was still darken much like the screenshot above.

Any ideas?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Thank you for the tip, Will do next time ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ..have the area within the rectangle be completely transparent while the outside was still darken much like the screenshot above.

- Create a `Rectangle` (`componentRect`) that is the size of the component being painted.
- Create an `Area` (`componentArea`) of that shape (`new Area(componentRect)`).
- Create an `Area` (`selectionArea`) of the `selectionRectangle`.
- Call `componentArea.subtract(selectionArea)` to remove the selected part.
- Call `Graphics.setClip(componentArea)`
- Paint the semi-transparent color.
- (Clear the clipping area if more paint operations are required).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels tell me about :P

Comment: @madProgrammer I gave andrew the correct answer for answering first, however I upvoted both of you.

Answer (score 5):

As Andrew has suggested (just beat me while I was finishing off my example)

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    g.setColor(Color.black); // black background

    Area area = new Area();
    // This is the area that will filled...
    area.add(new Area(new Rectangle2D.Float(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight())));

    g2.setColor(Color.GREEN.darker());

    int width = getWidth() - 1;
    int height = getHeight() - 1;

    int openWidth = 200;
    int openHeight = 200;

    int x = (width - openWidth) / 2;
    int y = (height - openHeight) / 2;

    // This is the area that will be uneffected
    area.subtract(new Area(new Rectangle2D.Float(x, y, openWidth, openHeight)));

    // Set up a AlphaComposite
    g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5f));
    g2.fill(area);

    g2.dispose();
}
```

[image: Show and Hide]

Comment: Niice..  :)  Well worth the 4 minute wait.

Comment: 1+ **but** I don't think that you should be calling `dispose()` on a Graphics object obtained from the JVM. This appears to be an error in the OP's code that you've propagated. Of course if you've created the Graphics object, then by all means dispose of it when done with it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes, you're right, I stole PatrickM's code and modified, bad on me. I've updated the example to use `g.create()` instead