# How to make a translucent JPanel within the region Jpanel

Tags: java, swing

I want to make a translucent `JPanel` for which I can choose the x-coordinate, y-coordinate, width and height. I have found some material that made a translucent `JPanel` that filled its parent container, but I don't need this effect. I need a translucent `JPanel` whose position can be specified in the parent container, such that only this area is translucent, while others in the parent container are opaque. I tried  this code but it is incorrect. The resultant area is smaller than the area I intend. What is wrong, or how I can get this effect?

```
public class TranslucentJPanel extends JPanel {

    private float transparency;

    public TranslucentJPanel(){
    }



    /**set the transparency
     * 
     * @param transparency:the transparency you want to set
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public void setTransparent(float transparency) {
        this.transparency = transparency;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D graphics2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        graphics2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(transparency));

        graphics2d.fill(getBounds());
        graphics2d.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use a `JLayer` (AKA `JXLayer`) to paint over the top of other components in a container, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274566/how-can-i-change-the-highlight-color-of-a-focused-jcombobox/25276658#25276658), otherwise you will need to use the glass pane

Comment: This [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127422/inner-transparent-selection-window-in-java-using-glasspane/12127579#12127579) is kind of the reverse of what you want (creates a whole in a translucent panel), but it might give you some ideas

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Thanks for your help.The first idea you given me is so difficult for me because I haven't known that class,And I will realize it now.The second example that you given is good,and I did get some idea.But after I have a translucency JPanel,I  will add some component over it.And that method is too tedious.So I'm sorry.

Comment: I thought you were adding the "transaprent" area over a preexisting container?  Can you provide some more details about what you are trying to achieve?  Maybe a use-case?  Might help solve the issue

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have added background in my `JFrame`,and  I have add a JPanel as parameter of `setContentPane()` method.In this JPanel ,I add another JPanel that I want to appoint position to show a Jlist,and I need  this JPanel  to be translucence.

Comment: I'm sorry that I want to show a picture but I don't know how to show it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, two things come to mind immediately...

First, don't use `getBounds`, the `Grapghics` context is already translated to the components `x`/`y` position, so you're doubling that up.  Instead, simply use `0x0` and provide the `width` and `height`, something like...

```
graphics2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
```

Also, remember, most Swing components are opaque by default, this includes the `JList`, `JScrollPane` and it's `JViewport`, you need to set these to be transparent if you want them to be see through at all.

Also, the "default" renderer that the `JList` uses also renderers it self as opaque, so you need to be able to supply your own if you want the items to be transparent...

[image: Translucent]

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
                model.addElement("Bananas");
                model.addElement("Apples");
                model.addElement("Pears");
                model.addElement("Grapes");
                model.addElement("Tim Tams");

                JList list = new JList(model);
                list.setCellRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {

                    @Override
                    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
                        super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
                        setOpaque(isSelected);
                        return this;
                    }

                });
                list.setOpaque(false);
                JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(list);
                sp.setOpaque(false);
                sp.getViewport().setOpaque(false);

                TranslucentPane tp = new TranslucentPane();
                tp.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                tp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                tp.add(sp);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setContentPane(new BackgroundPane());
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(tp);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TranslucentPane extends JPanel {

        private float alpha = 0.75f;

        public TranslucentPane() {
            setOpaque(false);
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(alpha));

            g2d.setColor(getBackground());
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

    public class BackgroundPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage background;

        public BackgroundPane() {
            try {
                background = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\shane\\Dropbox\\MegaTokyo\\thumnails\\megatokyo_omnibus_1_3_cover_by_fredrin-d4oupef.jpg"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(background.getWidth(), background.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            int x = (getWidth() - background.getWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - background.getHeight()) / 2;
            g.drawImage(background, x, y, this);
        }

    }

}
```