# Transparent GlassPane: overlapping issue

Tags: java, swing, transparency, graphics2d, glasspane

I'd like to display a `GlassPane` with a sort of blur effect. Broadly speaking, something like this:

[image]

I tried using as `GlassPane` a `JPanel` with transparent background. Here's the code of my custom panel.

```
JPanel glassPane = new JPanel(){
    @Override
    public void paint(java.awt.Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();         

        g2.setRenderingHint(java.awt.RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,java.awt.RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setComposite(java.awt.AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(0.5f));
        g2.setPaint(myColor);
        g2.fillRect(0,0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight());
        g2.dispose();
    };
}
```

The problem is that when I load the `GlassPane` I have a sort of overlapping issue. I.e. it seems that all the elements of the below UI (the ones displayed in the panel below the just loaded glass pane) are randomly mirrored on the `GlassPane`. This happens not only in `GlassPane`, but every time I try to use trnsparent colors with `Graphics2d`.
This is what i get:

[image]

Any idea on how to create a transparent `GlassPane` avoiding this annoting issue?

Comment: Have you been checking [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127422/inner-transparent-selection-window-in-java-using-glasspane?rq=1) (and it's answers)? It seems to be somewhat similar.

Comment: @el_chupacabra, I looked at that question before posting mine, but is not the same issue. My issue is about how to make transparent backgorund avoiding strange unexpected painting.

Comment: Components must obey the opacity contract - that is, if your component is translucent, [isOpaque()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#isOpaque%28%29) *must* return `false`. Otherwise the area below it does not necessarily get painted (and may contain garbage from temporary buffers).

Comment: @kiheru oh wow! That makes sense and perfectly works. I would've never figured it out. Thank you very much.

Comment: `something like this:` - so why don't you use the [Disabled Glass Pane](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/07/disabled-glass-pane/) where you found the image? `I would've never figured it out` - well that is exactly what the code in the `DisabledGlassPane` class does. So why didn't you start with something that was working and modify the existing code? That is make a change and still see if it works. If not, then you know the change you made caused the problem. Why reinvent the wheel from scratch if you don't understand the concept?

Comment: You mean perhaps something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215415/create-an-transparent-rectangle-over-blurred-background-in-jframe/23232618#23232618)? The core problem you're having is the fact that you've broken the paint chain by not calling `super.paint`, but you should be using `paintComponent` anyway